# Fair point system

Tags: permutations, arithmetic, scoring-algorithm

My friends and I play rounds of golf at 9 hole courses. In order to make the game more competitive, I've devised a point system for defining a winner other than just the lowest score at the end of the round. However, I'm unsure as to whether or not winning this scoring system is fair, in that is it possible to win the new scoring system without winning the overall score? The scoring system is as follows:

If you win a hole (you get the lowest score in that hole): **1pt**, 9 opportunities

If you win a set of 3 (you get the lowest score out of 3 holes): **2pts**, 3 opportunities (holes 1-3, 4-6, 7-9)

If you win the overall round (you get the lowest score overall): **5pts**, 1 opportunity

Any ties in the categories and the points are zeroed. For example, if 2 players shoot a low score of a 3 on a hole, neither receives the 1 point for that hole.

I've tried to figure out how to code the permutations, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way of calculating if it's a fair scoring system.

Comment: What do you mean by fair?

Comment: Can you win the new point system without having the lowest score in the overall round?

Comment: If you goal is to have the person with the lowest overall score win, then I don't understand what the point of this new system is.

Comment: @scoopfaze The goal isn't to have the person with the lowest overall score win, that's what the new system is trying to avoid. Say somebody shoots a couple of bad holes, and that keeps them from winning overall, but they won a set of 3 and individual hoes within that set. Could they win with the new system?

Comment: @Snyderman see my answer below. I hope it helps.

Comment: You might consider changing the points system from $(1,2,5)$ to $(2,4,11)$ or $(10,20,51)$ or something else of the form (even,even,odd). Doing so would guarantee that there's no tie in points if the overall score is not a tie, in effect breaking any tie in favor of the player with the lower overall score.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

Below are the scores for two players on each of the nine holes:

[image]

Obviously, the numbers are a bit absurd, but Player $2$ can certainly win without the lowest overall shot score.

Edit: I misread the original post: I added $3$ points instead of $2$ for each win of a three hole round. Please refer below to the comments until I have a chance to properly edit my post.

Comment: I think this is a helpful example, pointing out a way the new scoring system deviates from the old one.  Who should win?  I don't really know, but a number of tests like this can help decide what system is "fair".

Comment: I don’t play golf, so I don’t know if there are other peculiarities that go along with this. However, the fact that a player can win any one $9$ hold round by scoring several magnitudes worse than another player overall seems silly to me.

Comment: @scoopfaze, there's something called match play that does exactly that: it assigns one point for winning a hole, regardless of by how many shots, with the overall winner the player (or, often, team) with the highest point total. The Ryder Cup is played that way.

Comment: I just noticed, the total point scores here are miscomputed: This is actually a $10{:}10$ *tie*! Player 1 gets $(1+1+1)+2+5$, while Player 2 gets $(1+1+1+1+1+1)+(2+2)$. (I think you accidentally changed the $2$'s to $3$'s when you assigned points for the sets of three.)

Comment: You can fix things by letting Player 2 shoot a hole in one on holes 7 and 8 as well, giving them a total of $8\cdot1+3\cdot2=14$ points to Player 1s $1+5=6$.

Comment: Thanks for catching that!